# Fullpage.js - Anchor point on mobile not going back to top of the section when scrolled through

Tags: fullpage.js

I have this website -> https://life-5.webflow.io/ used with Fullpage.js.

If you open the website on mobile and try to tap one of the links in menu, everything goes fine.

For example "Výhody" are made from 5 tabs.. If you tap the link on top of the page you goes to 1st one, but if you scroll through the section and taps the "Výhody" once again, you get scrolled only to 5th tap and not to the top.

Any help how to fix this and makes the link always goes to the top of the section?
Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the `bigSectionsDestination` option.
From the [the fullpage.js documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js)

> bigSectionsDestination: (default null) Defines how to scroll to a section which size is bigger than the viewport. By default fullPage.js scrolls to the top if you come from a section above the destination one and to the bottom if you come from a section below the destination one. Possible values are top, bottom, null.